# Render a property of an object, within array, inside React Component's state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to pass and array of objects, fetched fro get request, to component's state, which has an array. I can successfully pass an array of numbers, or really anything but objects cause when i do that i recieve **this**:
[error_image.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGBuL.png)

Check out my .js files below, thanks.

**comment_item.js :**

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export class CommentItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      comments: []
    };
}

componentWillMount() {
  axios.get('api/v1/trip/2/comment/')
    .then(response => {
      const comments = [{a: 2, b: 4}, {a: 1, b: 3}]; //response.data should be here, but for your convenience I've put array of objects
      this.setState({comments});
    });
}

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                {this.state.comments[0].a}
            </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**comment.js :**

```
import React from 'react';

import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
import Divider from 'material-ui/Divider';
import List from 'material-ui/List/List';

import {CommentItem} from './comment_item';
import {CommentForm} from './comment_form';

const styles = {
  paper: {
      paddingLeft: 15,
      paddingRight: 15,
      paddingBottom: 15,

      marginLeft: 15,
      marginRight: 15,
      marginBottom: 15
  },

  divider: {
      backgroundColor: 'grey'
  }

};

export default class Comment extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Paper zDepth={5} rounded={false} style={styles.paper}>
                <div>
                    <List>
                        <CommentItem />
                    </List>

                    <Divider style={styles.divider}/>
                    <CommentForm/>
                </div>
            </Paper>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While rendering, `this.state.comments` isn't yet available, that's why you are getting `undefined` error. Try to add a condition, which will tell react to render given comment only if the `state.comments` variable is available.

```
<li>
   { this.state.comments.length ? this.state.comments[0].a : null }
</li>
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply :) I've tried to copy-paste your answer into my code and refresh the page, but I get the exact same error as before. Could you please explain me how it works, maybe I have to change something else too.

Comment: @Roman Strange. That's the only place where you are using that variable. If it's empty it shouldn't display anything and if it's not - it should render proper value. Please try to clear your cache and restart your app.

Comment: i think it should be `this.state.comments.length ? ......` because initial value is `[]` :)

Comment: @MayankShukla Yep, I've missed the default value of that variable, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the data `this.state.comments[0]` isn't available when you try to use it. So you need to perform a check before you use it

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                {this.state.comments[0]? this.state.comments[0].a: ''}
            </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

However I think your would like to map over the comments instead of displaying it. You could do it like

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                {this.state.comments && this.state.comments.map((comment) => {
                    <li>{comment.a}</li>
                })}
            </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you're checking `comments` and `length` too, like so -

```
(this.state.comments && this.state.comments.length > 0) ? 
    this.state.comments[0].a : null
```